# regex - positive lookahead - spaces

Tags: regex

I am using Positive Lookahead and can´t clear 2 spaces before my lovely string with \s* because quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width.

I can do it easily with remove function in .Net but i just want to clear it with rgx.

The string is:

```
Propocet na CZK Kurz   1.00000  Per CZK.
```

Regex is:

```
(?<=[Kurz]\s)\s*\d*.\d*(?=\s*Per\s[EeCc][UuZz][RrKk])
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/GaZKGB/1

There you can see spaces before number 1.00000, sometimes there is just one, sometimes more or less, and i want to clear it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to match only spaces between `Kurz` and the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Kurz\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*Per\s[EeCc][UuZz][RrKk])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GaZKGB/2).

Note:

- `[Kurz]` matches `r`, `z`, `u` or `K`, not a `Kurz` as a sequence of chars
- `\K` is a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- An unescaped `.` matches any char, and to match a literal `.` you need to escape it.

*Details*:

- `Kurz` - a word
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `(?=\s*Per\s[EeCc][UuZz][RrKk])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces, `Per`, a whitespace and then `E` or `C`, then `U` or `Z` and then `R` or `K` case insensitively.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Learned a lot of things with this !